# How to add an AppStore developer icon/logo

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have noticed the AppStore now has the ability to set a developer icon. I have scoured the web and gone through apple docs as well as ASC but can’t find how to set this icon. Does anyone know how this is done?[image]

Comment: I believe that this isn't a feature available to all developers